# Cannot resolve @Entity and javax.persistence.Entity in Springboot Gradle project

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I am following the guide on https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/ to start using MySQL for Gradle project, however, when I try to add in @Entity annotation it all

[image]

Here is my build.gradle, which follows the same thing on the website:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-accessing-data-mysql'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

    // JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...)
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'persistence-api', version: '1.0'

    // Use MySQL Connector-J
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: Remove from dependencies and can you try again? As far as I had used this does not need to be mentioned explicitly compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'persistence-api', version: '1.0'

Comment: Nope that doesnt work

Comment: Please share the complete build.gradle file

Answer (score 4):

Remove `compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'persistence-api', version: '1.0'` and try below after this as jar might be corrupted.

1. Run `./gradlew clean install` then check..
2. if above not work: then `delete ~/.gradle/caches` and again run gradle install command to re-import all dependencies.
3. Restart IDE and again import project.

Answer (score 1):

As you can seee in dependency tree of SpringBoot, `javax.persistence` is already included in `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and it's not `1.0`.

[image]

Remove:

`compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'persistence-api', version: '1.0'`

Comment: No, this doesnt work. It was because the orginial doesnt work so i add in additional line.